# SurfaceScrollViewer position is not updating when ScrollToHorizontalOffset is called

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, pixelsense

I am building an interactive campus map for a university on the Microsoft Surface 1.0 technology... I am working in WPF and C# with the Surface 1.0 SDK... I have dropped a large image into a `SurfaceScrollViewer` and there are various Canvas Elements that represent the buildings... There is another item that uses a selector to automatically move that building to the center of the screen.... I need to "Automatically" move the building on the map to the center of the screen when its name is pressed....

I am currently attempting to use: `ScrollToVerticalOffset()` and `ScrollToHorizontalOffset()` to move the `SurfaceScrollViewer` to the appropriate location. However the `SurfaceScrollViewer` never updates. I have searched and tried about three hundred different ways to do this but to no avail. Any suggestions upon how to achieve this would be great!

Comment: How do you call ScrollToVerticalOffset()? maybe you should provide some code.